# Exportacion Excel solo genere un registro

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

Exporto excel con laravel Excel pero al generar una consulta para mostrar el nombre de las llaves foraneas (id_ciudad=Bogota) solo me genera 1 solo registro

```
public function collection()
{
    return DB::table('personas')
        ->join('personas_naturales', 'personas.natural_id', '=', 'personas_naturales.id')
        ->join('tipo_documentos', 'tipo_documentos.id', '=', 'personas_naturales.id_tipoDocumento')
        ->join('clase_personas', 'clase_personas.id', '=', 'personas_naturales.id_clase')
        ->join('ciiu_actividades', 'ciiu_actividades.id', '=', 'personas_naturales.id_actividadesCiiu')
        ->join('ciiu_descriptores', 'ciiu_descriptores.id', '=', 'personas_naturales.descritores_id')
        ->join('ciudades', 'ciudades.id', '=', 'personas_naturales.ciudad_id')
        ->join('departamentos', 'departamentos.id', '=', 'personas_naturales.idDepartamento')
        ->join('entidad_bancarias', 'entidad_bancarias.id', '=', 'personas_naturales.entidadBancaria_id')
        ->join('dependencias', 'dependencias.id', '=', 'personas_naturales.dependencia_id')
        ->select(
            'tipo_documentos.nombreDocumento','personas_naturales.numeroDocumento','personas.nombre1',
            'personas.nombre2','personas.apellido','personas.apellido2','personas.direccion','personas.telefono',
            'personas.celular','personas.correo','ciudades.name','departamentos.nameDepartamento','personas.pais',
            'personas.responsableIVA','personas.regimenSimple',

            'personas_naturales.designadoSupervisor','personas_naturales.TipocuentaBancaria','personas_naturales.numeroCuenta',
            'personas_naturales.estadoCuenta','personas_naturales.tipoPersona',

            'clase_personas.nombre','personas_naturales.Subclase','ciiu_actividades.descripcion','ciiu_descriptores.actividad','entidad_bancarias.DenominacionAbreviadaEntidad',
            'dependencias.codigo'
        )
        ->get();
}
```

[image: Vista de regsitros]
[image: EXCEL]